# AngularJS: Format DateTimePicker on load

Tags: angularjs, umbraco7

I'm really struggling to get a datetimepicker working in a custom application within Umbraco 7. I've eventually got as far as creating a directive and saving the value back to the model but after hours of trying various examples I still have not been able to find a way to format the date on the initial load. The date format is '1901-02-07T01:05:00Z' until you interact with the datepicker. Here's what I have so far in my directive:

```
angular.module("umbraco.directives")
.directive('datetimepicker', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var ngModel = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
            element.datetimepicker({
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss',
                autoclose: true
            })
            .on('changeDate', function () {
                scope.$apply(function (scope) {
                    ngModel.assign(scope, element.val());
                });
            })                
        }
    }       
});
```

The HTML used is:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ShowFrom" datetimepicker />
```

Does anybody have any ideas on how I would achieve this? I've also tried using parsers and formatters with no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected the answer was to use parsers and formatters. I was originally getting an "unknown format provider" error when trying to use them, it turns out that adding **require: 'ngModel'** to the directive solved the problem. The $parser function converts the string back to a date for updating the model while the $formatter function takes the model value and formats it appropriately as a string.

Below is the final version of the directive. If anyone else would like to use the code then [here](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) is the datepicker this was written for.

```
angular.module("umbraco.directives")
.directive('datetimepicker', function ($parse, $filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            var ngModel = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
            element.datetimepicker({
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:00',
                autoclose: true
            })
            .on('changeDate', function () {
                scope.$apply(function (scope) {
                    ngModel.assign(scope, element.val());
                });
            });
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                return new Date(Date.parse(value));
            });
            ctrl.$formatters.push(function (value) {
                if (value.indexOf('0001-01-01') < 0)
                    return value.replace('T', ' ').replace('Z', '');
                else                    
                    return "";
            });
        }
    }       
});
```